# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "<url>": No address associated with hostname and End of input at character 0 of

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-asynctask

I've created an app that loads a question from my web services, and it works fine. But, sometimes it crashes and I do not get the reason why this is happening, especially because I have also given it the required permissions. It works fine, but at random, it crashes and gives me this report.

```
private void sendContinentQuestions(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Get the data (see above)
    JSONArray json = getJSONfromURL(id);
        try{
            for(int i=0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject jObject = json.getJSONObject(i);
                longitude":"72.5660200"
                String category_id = jObject.getString("category_id");
                String question_id = jObject.getString("question_id");
                String question_name = jObject.getString("question_name");
                String latitude = jObject.getString("latitude");
                String longitude = jObject.getString("longitude");
                String answer = jObject.getString("answer");
                String ansLatLng = latitude+"|"+longitude ; 
                Log.v("## data:: ###",question_id+"--"+question_name+"-cat id-"+category_id+"--ansLatLng "+ansLatLng+" answer: "+answer);

                all_question.add(new QuestionData(game_id,category_id,question_id,question_name,ansLatLng,answer));
            }
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
    }


}
 public JSONArray getJSONfromURL(int id){

    String response = "";
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(Consts.GET_URL+"index.php/Api/getQuestion?cat_id="+id);
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        InputStream is = http.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        response = br.readLine();
        Log.v("###Response :: ###",response);
        http.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    //try parse the string to a JSON object
    JSONArray jArray = null;
    try{

        jArray = new JSONArray(response);

    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

---

```
11-13 15:02:52.307: W/System.err(8012): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.xyz.com": No address associated with hostname
11-13 15:02:52.317: W/System.err(8012):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
11-13 15:02:52.317: W/System.err(8012):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-13 15:02:52.317: W/System.err(8012):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-13 15:02:52.317: W/System.err(8012):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
11-13 15:02:52.317: W/System.err(8012):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
11-13 15:02:52.317: W/System.err(8012):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
11-13 15:02:52.317: W/System.err(8012):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
11-13 15:02:52.317: W/System.err(8012):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
11-13 15:02:52.317: W/System.err(8012):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
11-13 15:02:52.317: W/System.err(8012):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
11-13 15:02:52.317: W/System.err(8012):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
11-13 15:02:52.317: W/System.err(8012):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
11-13 15:02:52.317: W/System.err(8012):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
11-13 15:02:52.317: W/System.err(8012):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
11-13 15:02:52.327: W/System.err(8012):     at com.abc.xyz.ContinentActivity.getJSONfromURL(ContinentActivity.java:400)
11-13 15:02:52.327: W/System.err(8012):     at com.abc.xyz.ContinentActivity.sendContinentQuestions(ContinentActivity.java:327)
11-13 15:02:52.327: W/System.err(8012):     at com.abc.xyz.ContinentActivity.access$2(ContinentActivity.java:323)
11-13 15:02:52.327: W/System.err(8012):     at com.abc.xyz.ContinentActivity$LoadQuestions.doInBackground(ContinentActivity.java:254)
11-13 15:02:52.327: W/System.err(8012):     at com.abc.xyz.ContinentActivity$LoadQuestions.doInBackground(ContinentActivity.java:1)
11-13 15:02:52.327: W/System.err(8012):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-13 15:02:52.327: W/System.err(8012):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-13 15:02:52.327: W/System.err(8012):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-13 15:02:52.327: W/System.err(8012):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-13 15:02:52.337: W/System.err(8012):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-13 15:02:52.337: W/System.err(8012):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-13 15:02:52.337: W/System.err(8012): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
11-13 15:02:52.337: W/System.err(8012):     at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
11-13 15:02:52.337: W/System.err(8012):     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
11-13 15:02:52.337: W/System.err(8012):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
11-13 15:02:52.337: W/System.err(8012):     ... 24 more
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/log_tag(8012): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
11-13 15:02:52.337: W/dalvikvm(8012): threadid=194: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417c1700)
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012):     at com.abc.xyz.ContinentActivity.sendContinentQuestions(ContinentActivity.java:328)
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012):     at com.abc.xyz.ContinentActivity.access$2(ContinentActivity.java:323)
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012):     at com.abc.xyz.ContinentActivity$LoadQuestions.doInBackground(ContinentActivity.java:254)
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012):     at com.abc.xyz.ContinentActivity$LoadQuestions.doInBackground(ContinentActivity.java:1)
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-13 15:02:52.337: E/AndroidRuntime(8012):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

Comment: Are you connected to the Internet?

Comment: Do you get the response printed in your log ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked for internet connection.

Comment: Check if the phone can access this url (in the browser for exemple)

Comment: Do not try with simulator, I have had the same issue. And I have spent 1 day trying to figure it out. Finally, my solution was to use a real android device for testing.

Comment: all these answers are bad seriously!!. For poor connectivity use-cases, UnknownHostException is thrown no matter what while being on the mobile network. Response just doesn't come and you should just timeout the request for handling such cases.

Answer (score 295, accepted):

I encountered this problem too, reconnecting the WiFi can solve this.

For us ,we can check if the phone can resolve the host to IP when we start application. If it cannot resolve, tell the user to check the WiFi and then exit.

Comment: I had to turn off my phone !

Comment: Is this issue still exist in Android 7? I can encounter this behavior randomly on application open. The network connection is available for the application, but it connect access to the web services. What could cause to this? Several devices in the network have the same problem.

Comment: Can there be some way to give alert or toast to user because programmers may understand the problem but the user does not he won't come to stackoverflow he will just uninstall the app..

Comment: man what a saviour. Seems like some bug of wifi. Disconnecting worked like a charm.

Answer (score 33):

If reconnecting the WiFi doesn't work for you, try reboot your device.

This works for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: omg... a wifi problem not the android problems....! i should put the code for checking whether the internet is exist or not first. Thanks @Jiyeh

Answer (score 25):

I had the same exception in the simulator (Android Studio on OSX) but connecting to the same URL on the iOS simulator worked fine... Looks like it all stemmed from the fact I'd be running the simulator whilst connected to a personal hotspot for my internet connection and then came back later while connected to wifi and the simulator didn't like the new internet connection for some reason, seems like it thought the old hotspot was the current connection, which was no longer working..

Closing and relaunching the simulator worked!

Comment: Same here, worked after restarting the emulator

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error and the issue was that I was on VPN and I didn't realize it. After disconnecting from the VPN and reconnecting to my WIFI network, the problem was resolved.

Comment: This solution worked for me with Disconnecting VPN

Answer (score 8):

Missed to configure tag in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this error when running my Android app on my home WiFi, then trying to run it on different WiFi without closing my simulator.

Simply closing the simulator and re-launching the app worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host “”...

I'm running Visual Studio 2019 and Xamarin.

I also switched back to my WiFi but was on a hot spot.

I solved this by clean swiping the emulator.  Restore to factory settings.  Then re-running visual studio xamarin app which wil redeploy your app again to the fresh emulator.

It worked.  I thought I was going to battle for days to solve this.  Luckily this post pointed me in the right direction.

I could not understand how it worked perfectly before and then stopped with no code change.

This is my code for reference:

```
using var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(sb.ToString());
string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

I was testing my application with the Android emulator and I solved this by turning off and turning on the Wi-Fi on the Android emulator device! It worked perfectly.

Comment: I did the same thing, only with mobile data.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but with small difference. I had added NetworkConnectionCallback to check situation when internet connection had changed at runtime, and checking like this before sending all requests:

```
private fun isConnected(): Boolean {
    val activeNetwork = cManager.activeNetworkInfo
    return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected
}
```

There can be state like CONNECTING (you can see iе when you turn on wifi, icon starts blinking, after connecting to network, image is static).
So, we have two different states: one CONNECT another CONNECTING, and when Retrofit tried to send request internet connection is disabled and it throws UnknownHostException. 
I forgot to add another type of exception in function which was responsible for sending requests.

```
try{
//for example, retrofit call
}
catch (e: Exception) {
        is UnknownHostException -> "Unknown host!"
        is ConnectException -> "No internet!"
        else -> "Unknown exception!"
    }
```

It's just a tricky moment that can by related with this problem.

Hope, I will help somebody)

Comment: What is cManager?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, but with Glide. When I was going to disconnect from wifi and reconnect (just like it was suggested here), I noticed that I was in Airplane mode ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem
and the solution I did was to reboot my android device or emulator.
it solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the permission on the top in the manifest section

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score -3):

I had this issue on Android 10,

Changed `targetSdkVersion 29` to `targetSdkVersion 28` issue resolved. Not sure what is the actual problem.

I think not a good practice, but it worked.

***before:***

`compileSdkVersion 29`

`minSdkVersion 14`

`targetSdkVersion 29`

***Now:***

`compileSdkVersion 29`

`minSdkVersion 14`

`targetSdkVersion 28`

Comment: Your solution worked for me! Thanks a lot! Experienced on Samsung Galaxy M31 with Android 10.

Comment: This is not the solution, it is very restrictive