# Unable to resolve host pokeAPI

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get datas from pokeAPI for my android API.  I have followed the instructions into this page https://github.com/PokeAPI/pokekotlin.

I have add in bluid.gradle(module:app) dependencies :

```
compile 'me.sargunvohra.lib:pokekotlin:2.3.0'
```

In build.gradle(Project):

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://jcenter.bintray.com' }
}
```

}

I have add this permission in manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The code for get pokemon species is in a asynctask :

```
 private class DownloadPokeAPIData extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,PokemonSpecies> {

    protected PokemonSpecies doInBackground(Integer...numbers){
        PokeApi pokeApi = new PokeApiClient();
        try {
            return pokeApi.getPokemonSpecies(numbers[0].intValue());
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("AsyncTask error",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(PokemonSpecies result) {
        if(result != null) ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.pokemon)).setText(result.getName());
    }


}
```

The call of DownloadPokeAPIData is in onCreate of MainActivity: `new DownloadPokeAPIData().execute(new Integer(1));`

But i still get this message:

```
AsyncTask error: Unable to resolve host "pokeapi.co": No address associated with hostname
```

Do you know where the problem came from ?

Comment: Also, try changing the device/network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951466/java-net-unknownhostexception-unable-to-resolve-host-url-no-address-associ) and I have to add this permission in my manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

It's work now . Thanks for your responses.