# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host exception on Marshmallow

Tags: java, android

The code I use:

```
GlobalClass gcVar = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
String URL        = gcVar.getUrl();
String url        = URL + "List_Divisions?inParam=";
Log.d("Login", "URL to get list of division===" + url);
String param      = "{'ACTIVE_YN':'Y'}";            
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

client.setTimeout(150000);
client.setMaxRetriesAndTimeout(1, 150000);
client.get(url+param, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
```

Excepction that I get...

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "14.141.61.220.static-Pune.vsnl.net.in": No address associated with hostname
```

`

I have given all the permissions, Internet is working, when we hit URL on browser it works fine but when url is called from **Android version 6 and below 6 it gives unknownhostexception**. It work fine on **Nougat**.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "<url>": No address associated with hostname and End of input at character 0 of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951466/java-net-unknownhostexception-unable-to-resolve-host-url-no-address-associ)

Comment: Thank you for the link,but my internet working ,when i hit url from phone browser i get the response.. but from application i get unkownhost exception on marshmallow..it works on nougat

Comment: Are you sure you declared the internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: share your code.

Comment: I have given  permissions <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <u

Comment: Are you making HTTPS request connection?