# Retrofit Call only working WiFi and stops working on Mobile Data

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am working on an android app. In my app i am using retrofit to GET and POST and data from a web service. If i am using WiFi, or if i am in certain place, i get a response and everything works fine. But, as soon as i switch to a mobile data, or I move to a different area, it stops working. I tried to debug and see the log cat, and the error i am getting is as follows:

```
2020-08-31 23:17:49.676 3470-3470/com.example.myscheduler W/Glide: Load failed for https://www.example.com/images/large_group2.png with size [289x289]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.UnknownHostException(Unable to resolve host "www.example.com": No address associated with hostname)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.UnknownHostException(Unable to resolve host "www.example.com": No address associated with hostname)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.UnknownHostException(Unable to resolve host "www.example.com": No address associated with hostname)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.example.com": No address associated with hostname
```

Also, when on mobile data, it works if it is connected to VPN and stops working when disconnected from VPN.
I have the Internet permission in the android manifest file. What should i do to solve this.

Any help would be a great help and much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you access the website on your phone normally? I mean in the app it doesn’t seem to work, but what about browsers?

Comment: Yes. it works in browsers.

Comment: Seems like your internet is not working on the phone? Have you restricted the use of internet for this app via settings on phone?

Comment: Not at all. The app works fine if it is on WiFi, but when i switch to Mobile Data, I get the above error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951466/java-net-unknownhostexception-unable-to-resolve-host-url-no-address-associ

Comment: Did you try by removing **www.** or Changing **https** to **http** ?

Comment: Thank you, but I saw this solution. This recommends to reconnect the WiFi, but my problem is with Mobile Data. The app needs to work on mobile data as well.

Comment: i tried to change it to Http, but to no avail.

Comment: Can you check with any url: http://cdn3.nflximg.net/images/3093/2043093.jpg

Comment: Yes i tested it and it does work on WiFi. The problem is not with URLs, when switching to mobile data, it stops working. I tried to handle the onFailure() method from Retrofit and has an instanceof IOException. Why would it work on WiFi and not on mobile data.