# Unable to resolve host "mywebsite.com": No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I have an android application where I send http requests to an api via Retrofit2/OkHttp. Everything was working fine for 2 weeks. 2 days ago my site was suspended. It reopened today.Error messages started to appear from some users. Users say "Unable to login to the application!". When I checked the logs, I saw something like this ;

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to 
resolve host "mywebsite.com": No address associated with hostname
```

Some users are still able to login to the application.I can't make sense of this.

How can I fix this immediately?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951466/java-net-unknownhostexception-unable-to-resolve-host-url-no-address-associ

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3919

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your mywebsite.com DNS has just not been propagated out fully yet. Check with your hosting service on how long that can take.

For instance, this is what one web hosting service says about it:
https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/when-will-my-domain-start-working-propagation