# Android emulator: No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, retrofit2, bluestacks

I'm using **BlueStack** for the android emulator. The `API(Retrofit)` call response is:
Log:
Unable to resolve host "URL": No address associated with hostname

Comment: seems to be duplicate question. can you check if this answers it -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355498/unable-to-resolve-host-url-here-no-address-associated-with-host-name

Comment: @emilpmp Your link I had seen before, not those reason.

Answer (score 0):

try connect and reconnecting to your wifi(Network) if it doesent work try rebooting your device

also see this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20277925/13659384

Comment: Not wifi's reason

Comment: then provide more details please